# How to set gradients to Zero without optimizer?

Tags: gradient, pytorch

Between mutliple `.backward()` passes I'd like to set the gradients to zero. Right now I have to do this for every component seperately  (here these are `x` and `t`), is there a way to do this "globally" for all affected variables? (I imagine something like `z.set_all_gradients_to_zero()`.)

I know there is `optimizer.zero_grad()` if you use an optimizer, but is there also a direct way without using an optimizer?

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(3, requires_grad = True)
t = torch.randn(3, requires_grad = True)
y = x + t
z = y + y.flip(0)

z.backward(torch.tensor([1., 0., 0.]), retain_graph = True)
print(x.grad)
print(t.grad)
x.grad.data.zero_()  # both gradients need to be set to zero 
t.grad.data.zero_()
z.backward(torch.tensor([0., 1., 0.]), retain_graph = True)
print(x.grad)
print(t.grad)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use [`nn.Module.zero_grad()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.zero_grad). In fact, `optim.zero_grad()` just calls `nn.Module.zero_grad()` on all parameters which were passed to it.

There is no reasonable way to do it globally. You can collect your variables in a list

```
grad_vars = [x, t]
for var in grad_vars:
    var.grad = None
```

or create some hacky function based on `vars()`. Perhaps it's also possible to inspect the computation graph and zero the gradient of all leaf nodes, but I am not familiar with the graph API. Long story short, you're expected to use the object-oriented interface of `torch.nn` instead of manually creating tensor variables.